# Is the inverse of a finitely generated $A$-submodule of $\mathrm{Frac}(A)$ still finitely generated?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, finitely-generated

**Context.** I recently realized that the definition of a fractional ideal of an integral domain $A$ I knew was probably the wrong one.

To give some context, let me give two different possible definitions of a fractional ideal.

Let $A$ be an integral domain, with field of fractions $K$.

**Definition 1. ("wrong one")** A fractional ideal of $A$ is a finitely generated $A$-submodule of $K$.

**Definition 2. ("right one")** A fractional ideal of $A$ is an $A$-submodule of $K$ of the form $x\mathfrak{a},$ where $x\in K^\times$ and $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal of $A$.

Recall that if $I$ is an $A$-submodule of $K$, then $I^{-1}=\{x\in K\mid xI\subset A\}$. We say that $I$ is invertible if $II^{-1}=A$.

Clearly, a fractional ideal in the sense of Definition $1$ is also a fractional ideal in the sense of definition $2$. The opposite direction is not necessarily true if $A$ is not noetherian.

It is also known that an **invertible** submodule $I$ is automatically finitely generated, so the two definitions coincide for invertible fractional ideals.

Definition 2 seems more tractable since one may prove easily that if $I$ is a fractional ideal in the sense of Definition $2$, then the same holds for $I^{-1}$.

Here comes finally my question:

**Question.** Let $I$ be an arbitrary finitely generated $A$-submodule of $K$. Is $I^{-1}$ necessarily finitely generated? If not, what about if we assume $A$ noetherian?

(In other words, is the inverse of a fractional ideal in the sense of Definition 1 still a fractional ideal in the same sense?)

I think the answer should be **NO** but I can't cook up any counterexample for the moment.

Thank you in advance for your insights.

Comment: Well the definitions are equivalent in the Noetherian case so you already know the answer is yes in that case.

Comment: @EricWolfsey. Yes, of course, I don't why i missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field and consider the ring $A=k[x,xy,xy^2,xy^3,\dots]\subset k[x,y]$ and the $A$-submodule $I\subset k(x,y)$ generated by $y$ and $1$.  Then $I^{-1}$ is the ideal in $A$ generated by $x,xy,xy^2,\dots$ which is not finitely generated.